# JAWS screen reader does not read headings/paragraph text in vscode webview

Tags: visual-studio-code, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I'm building a vscode extension which has multiple webviews that are expected to be accessible with JAWS screen reader. While JAWS correctly reads the information of tab-able controls in the UI along with the labels/description associated with it, it skips through all the standalone text. I.e., it does not read headings, subheadings, paragraph text, general descriptive text in the page. Is there any setting I must use to read the page text?

I noticed that JAWS also doesn't read the headings in the vscode welcome page -
Here the headings 'Start', 'Walkthroughs', and 'Recent' are not being read. Is this a bug or am I using JAWS wrong?

[image: vscode welcome page]

Comment: How are you navigating to the headings? Using the JAWS shortcut key 'H'? And it doesn't work?

Comment: @slugolicious I was trying INSERT+down arrow to read the full page but it only reads the page title and no content in the page. Just tried with 'H' key but JAWS just announces 'H'?

Comment: If you hear 'H' instead of navigating to a heading, it sounds like you need to switch modes in JAWS.  Try Ins+Z to toggle modes then try 'H' again.